# Mongoose - need to update property within multiple elements of deeply nested Array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose, nested

This is my Model:

```js
{
Category: {
    name: catname
    products: [
      {
      name: productName
      items: [
          {
          ts: 1234345
          ....
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to update multiple Items (their "ts" property) and return them with res.send().

I tried this but its only updating one.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < buyCount; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    if (!item.selldate && item.replaced.length < 1) {
        // set a selldate for item and save the item
        item.selldate = Date.now();
        req_items.push(item);
    }
    // save the items with a selldate to mark them as sold
    Category.getProductsOfCategory(catId, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
             res.send({status: false, data: err})
        } else {
             console.log(data.products.id(productId).items.id(item._id))
             data.products.id(productId).items.id(item._id).selldate = Date.now();
             data.save();
        }
    });
}
res.send({toPay: toPay, totalPrice: totalPrice, p: req_items})
```

Can you please help me? How do i update for example 2 or 3 at one time?

Comment: the `save` operation is asynchronous. You don't seem to waiting for the data to save before sending your response.

Comment: How to wait for it?

Comment: you can pass a callback to the save function with just one parameter, err, inside that function, if err is null, save it's complete

Comment: Since you are updating multiple objects, you need to use Promise.all to wait for all objects to update. Then once Promise.all resolves with all your changes, you can issue a final res.send call. You need to read about promises and promise.all and look at the mongoose api docs.

Comment: @GovindRai How to do this in a for loop with dynamic count of items?